# Troubles marshaling dates

Tags: java, marshalling

Im marshalling a java object as follow:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class NegociacionesMobile {

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JsonDateAdapter.class)
  private Date fecha; 

  public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
  }

  public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
  }
}
```

And the jSonDateAdapter is:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class JsonDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

  @Override
  public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(v);
    return date;
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(v);
    return date;
  }
}
```

When marshalling never enters in to JSonAdparter's marshal function and the date is transform to this weird format. -> ,"fecha":1333110291000,

Some one knows whats happening?

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you associate the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JsonDateAdapter.class)` to the getter instead of the field?

Comment: That "weird" format is probably the standard timestamp format as returned by `Date.getTime()`, that is the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1970).

Comment: Thanks for the format info, and if i put the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JsonDateAdapter.class) behaves the same way, in fact never enters to that class, dont know why

Comment: What is the data that you are sending and where is it printing `1333110291000`?

Comment: Im trying to send a normal date i.e 2011-03-02 etc and the 1333110291000 is how the the object's date is marshalled. I tried all your suggestions but nothing change and I have putted break  point in the  JsonDateAdapter adapter class but it never enters. The object complete object is marshaled like this:{"idNegocicion":202,"idArticulo":"0","fecha":1333368053000,"isUsuarioLocal":1,"comentario":"xx"}

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `fecha` with `@XmlElement`.